# Why does this regular expression in cmd findstr work?

Tags: regex, batch-file, cmd, findstr

I need to create a cmd script (and somehow I did) that extracts some lines of text from a series of files and puts them in a new txt file.

The source files are like this:

```
%
!
! AAA
!
! ------------------------ SOME TEXT ABCDEFGHIJKLMN --------------------------
!
! BBB
! ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
! T5 PUNTA ø 6.5/9.5~  $ 63~
! ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
! T12 PUNTA ø 2.5~  $ 39~
! ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
! 
! SOME OTHER TEXT
! 
!  1]  ABC
!  2]  DEF
!  3]  ...

OTHER LINE 1
OTHER LINE 2
ETC

%
```

And the lines I need to extract are the ones between two `"! ----------------------------------------------------------------------------"` so, in this case, `T5 PUNTA ø 6.5/9.5~  $ 63~` and `T12 PUNTA ø 2.5~  $ 39~`.

I was trying some regular expressions with `findstr` to match a line with `!` only after the relevant lines, which indicates the end of the search, until I came up (by pure chance) with an instruction that matches all and only the lines that I need (luck, I guess).

The snippet is this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if exist output.txt ( break > output.txt )
for /r <path> %%g in (<filename>) do (
    ...
    for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (%%g) do (
        echo %%a | findstr /r /c:^\!$ >nul
        if errorlevel 1 (...)
        ) else ( echo %%a >> srcoutput.txt
            ...
        )
    )
)
```

Please focus on the instruction `echo %%a | findstr /r /c:^\!$ >nul`.
This, for a reason I don't know, matches only the lines `T5 PUNTA ø 6.5/9.5~  $ 63~` and `T12 PUNTA ø 2.5~  $ 39~`. Which is exactly what I want, but I don't know why it works!

Can someone help me understand why this simple expression `^\!$` works?
In my (wrong) understanding, it should match only a line with a single `!` (which I had escaped, because otherwise it didn't work) at the beginning and at the end.

Thank you in advance

Comment: @Gerhard yes, sorry, matches .. not removes.

Comment: @Francesco, I suggest you open `cmd` and run `findstr /?` and read some of the useful help files.

Comment: Actually this just returns lines that contain a `$`-sign, that's it…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the comand line:

```cmd
echo %%a | findstr /r /c:^\!$ >nul
```

just returns lines that contain a `$`-character.

This is what happens, step by step:

- the command line becomes parsed to (assuming `%%a` holds `<expanded text>`):

  ```cmd
    echo <expanded text> | findstr /r /c:\!$ >nul
  ```

  so the (unquoted) caret (`^`) disappears as it is the escape character for `cmd`; since `\` has no special meaning, you could just omit the `^` after all;
- since delayed expansion is enabled (actually unnecessarily), the `!`-sign disappears, because there is only one, so the command line becomes:

  ```cmd
    echo <expanded text> | findstr /r /c:\$ >nul
  ```
- the `\`-symbol acts as an escape character (though particularly for `findstr`!), so the `$`-sign loses its special meaning in regular expression (`/R`) mode (namely to anchor a match to the end of a line) and is therefore treated as a literal character;
- the left side of the pipe passes on the text `<expanded text>`  (with a trailing <kbd>SPACE</kbd> since there is one before the `|`), and the right side eventually searches for literal `$`-characters in that text;

You would achieve the exactly same result using the following command line instead:

```cmd
echo %%a | findstr /C:$ > nul
```

though I would rather write it as:

```cmd
echo(%%a| findstr /C:"$" > nul
```

to avoid the trailing <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and to safely echo any text.

---

For this task I would probably go for another approach (see all the explanatory `rem` remarks):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=D:\Target\Path"        & rem // (path to root directory)
set "_MASK=*.txt"                 & rem // (name or mask of files to process)
set "_SAVE=D:\Path\To\output.txt" & rem // (location of output file)
rem // Gather line-feed character:
(set ^"_LF=^
%= blank line =%
^")
rem // Gather carriage-return character:
for /F %%C in ('copy /Z "%~f0" nul') do set "_CR=%%C"

rem // Open output file only once and write to it:
> "%_SAVE%" (
    rem // Find matching files and loop through them:
    for /R "%_ROOT%" %%F in ("%_MASK%") do (
        rem // Check for file existence (only necessary when a dedicated name is given):
        if exist "%%~F" (
            rem // Store path of current file:
            set "FILE=%%~F"
            rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid troubles with `!`:
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            rem // Remove remaining quotes (only necessary when a dedicated name is given):
            set "FILE=!FILE:"=!
            rem /* Do a multi-line search by `findstr`, which only returns the first line;
            rem    the searched string is:
            rem     # anchored to the beginning of a line,
            rem     # an `!`, a space and a `T`, then
            rem     # some arbitrary text (without line-breaks), then
            rem     # a line-break, then another `!` and a space, then
            rem     # a sequence of one or more `-`,
            rem     # anchored to the end of a line;
            rem    only the portion before the explicit line-break is then returned: */
            findstr /R /C:"^^^! T.*~!_CR!!_LF!^! --*$" "!FILE!"
            endlocal
        )
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

This does not exactly search for lines between `! ---` etc., but it searches for two adjacent lines where the first one begins with `!` + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> + `T` and ends with `~`, and the second one consists of `!` + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> + a sequence of one or more `-`.

If the input file contains Unix-/Linux-style line-breaks rather than DOS-/Windows-style ones, replace `!_CR!!_LF!` in the `findstr` search string in the script by `!_LF!`.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to post this as a potential method of achieving your intented goal. It uses a different methodology from the currently accepted answer, the idea is to retrieve the `! ----etc.` line numbers, then determine if the lines between any two of them have the required content. *This means that it isn't looking to match specific content between those lines and should therefore work, whichever characters your strings are formed using.*

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "InFile=somefile.ext"
Set "OutFile=someoutfile.ext"
Set "$#="&For /F "Delims=:" %%G In (
    '"%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /RNC:"^! --*$" "%InFile%""')Do (
    Set /A _2=%%G-2&Call Set "$#= %%G %%$#%%"&Call Set "$2= %%_2%% %%$2%%")
If Not Defined $# Echo No Matches&%__AppDir__%timeout.exe -3&Exit /B
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For %%G In (%$2%)Do If "!$#: %%G =!"=="%$#%" Set "$2=!$2: %%G =!"
For %%G In (%$2%)Do Set /A _1=%%G+1&Set "$1= !_1! !$1!"
EndLocal&(For %%G In (%$1%)Do For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=]" %%H In (
    '%__AppDir__%find.exe /V /N "" "%InFile%"^
     ^|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe "^\[%%G\]"')Do Echo %%I)>"%OutFile%"
GoTo :EOF
```

*Just change your input file and output file names on lines `3` and `4`, as required.*

*Please note that I'm unble to test this, so it may not work, or could possibly work in the wrong way. Please test it on files with various similar formats, before using it for real!*